# Total current in a closed loop using Ampere's Circuital Law

Tags: current, electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I would like to reassure my concept on this question:

> [image: Question]

I have 2 different ways to solve this question:

1. Determining the direction of current in the loop using right-hand solenoid loop and adding them up to get \$2I\$. With option C as the answer.
2. Because all the wires are in 1 closed loop with the same direction, we should just add them up together to get a total of \$6I\$. With option E as the answer.

Comment: In "1.", the intuition that the wire carrying 2I goes through the loop in the other direction is correct. The wire didn't turn around, but the loop did. The reasoning in "2." is wrong for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with 3l+l-2l, if you rotate the middle current and loop so they all look alike it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer is A. For 3I and I currents the loop is counter clock wise direction which is opposite to magnetic field created by them. Hence - 4I. However for 2I current the magnetic flied and loop are in the same direction. Hence it is 2I. 
Net  = -4I + 2I = -2I